# Querying a self relationship category table

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am trying to optimize my php code for the following table

```
Create table categories (
    cat_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id Int UNSIGNED,
    cat_name Varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (cat_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

To get all categories and subcategories i use one query for querying only parent categories and then issue an individual query to get the sub categories.

here is my code for listing the all main categories

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL");
```

To list individual subcategories of each category i use following query

```
$sub_result = mysql_query ("SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE parent_id=$cat_id");
```

I have 30 categories so the above issues 30 queries on each page, I am trying to minimize the number of queries. Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The article on [managing hierarchical data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) might give you some inspiration. Don't be discouraged by the fact that it's on MySQL site, the main ideas are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough in MySQL because of lack of support for recursive queries.

There are several alternative ways to structure your table so you can query all descendants of a hierarchy in a single query.  But they involve changing the way you store data.

See my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) for examples demonstrating several solutions.